# Angular: erro ao tentar manipular valor de input - property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Eu estou tendo problemas ao tentar pegar o value de um input para o limpar, o código está num script .ts (usado no Angular 7), código abaixo:

```
document.querySelector('.input').value = "";
```

Erro ao compilar o código

> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'

Está faltando algo? Pois fiz testes utilizando o console e ocorreu tudo certo.

Comment: O melhor seria pegar do seu NgModel ou do seu ReactiveForms dependendo de qual vc estiver usando. Isso de pegar o valor do input através do DOm era prática de jquery antiga e não é recomendado principalmente com angular.

Comment: Irei pesquisar sobre o NgModel e ReactiveForms, obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era do tipo que não poderia ser Element, consegui solucionar com o código abaixo, convertendo de Element para Input:

```
(document.querySelector('.input') as HTMLInputElement).value = "";
```